# How To Create Dynamic MySQL Update Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is for me at least a slightly complicated topic, I'm creating a website which requires the ability to update information that has been entered into it and saved to a database. I've managed to get this to work effectively with a single attribute but I wish to modify it to be able to change any selected attribute. The selected attribute will be selected from a drop down menu in the below code from a page called update.php

```
<form action="updatejob.php" method="POST">
            <label for="jobs_id">Job ID:</label><input type="text" name="jobs_id" />
            <select name="updatecategory">
                <option value="title">Title</option>
                <option value="category">Category</option>
                <option value="salary">Salary</option>
                <option value="location">Location</option>
                <option value="description">Description</option>
            </select>
            <label for="newcontent">Updated Information: </label><input type="text" name="newcontent" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

The query I've attempted to write is in a file called updatejob.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['jobs_id'])){
         $updatetitle= $pdo->prepare('UPDATE jobs SET :updatecategory  =  :newcontent WHERE jobs_id = :jobs_id');
         unset($_POST['submit']);
         $updatetitle->execute($_POST);
        header("Location:admin.php");
}
```

As I mentioned above this works fine when I have it set to one particular attribute which isn't in a selection box. Previously I had it set up so the user could only edit the title of a record using just a text box. To be honest I'm not even sure if this is possible or if I'm particularly close to the correct way of going about this so all help is appreciated!

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to select the column to be updated based on the value of the `<select>`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I probably wasn't too clear.

Comment: No, you were clear; it's just an interesting concept. I'm working up a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. [According to the PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), you aren't allowed to bind identifiers such as column names, so you need to use some variation on dynamic query, which normally opens you to injection attacks. The most robust solution that comes to mind is to have a lookup table indexing the `<select>` values to the column names, which is used to "fill in the blanks" in a prepared statement.

```
column_lookup
+----------+----------+
| selval   | colname  |
+==========+==========+
| title    | title    |
| category | category |
| location | location |
| etc.     | etc.     |
```

You would then do something like

```
$colsql = "SELECT colname FROM column_lookup WHERE selval = :selval"
$colstmt = $dbh->prepare($colsql);
$res = $colstmt->execute(array(':selval' => $_POST['updatecategory']));

$updsql = "UPDATE jobs
             SET " . $res->fetchColumn(0) . " =  :newcontent
             WHERE jobs_id = :jobs_id";
$updstmt = $dbh->prepare($updsql);
$updstmt->bindValue(':newcontent', $_POST['newcontent'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$updstmt->bindValue(':jobs_id', $_POST['jobs_id'], PDO::PARAM_whatever);
$updstmt->execute;
```

This has the effect of sanitizing all inputs through prepared statements while still dynamically generating the `UPDATE` query.

It is my custom to leave error handling as an exercise for the reader. In particular, I have omitted any attempt to validate the datatype of `jobs_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a blocker in your current methodology. Aside from not sanitizing your data. You're attempting to parameterize a column. The way a prepare statement works is it sends/caches the query plan and sends the parameters separately. Thus you can't bind part of the query plan because its sent/cached beforehand.

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that
>   will be issued multiple times with different parameter values
>   optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver
>   to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and
>   meta information, and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by
>   eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.

[php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

This doesn't mean you *can't* have dynamic aspects to your query plan, you just can't have them bound.

**Example of dynamic query plan.**

```
<?php 
$whiteListedColumns = array(
    "valid", "schema", "etc"
);

$updateCategory = in_array($_POST["updatecategory"], $whiteListedColumns) ? $updateCategory : null;
if($updateCategory) {
    //Sanitize Here
    //Its really important to understand what the filter reference docs.
    //You can skip for now. 
    $params = array(
        "newcontent" => filter_var($_POST["newcontent"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES),
        "jobs_id" => (int) $_POST["jobs_id"],
    );

    //Notice I simply concatenated the query string (didn't bind)
    $sql = "UPDATE jobs 
    SET {$updateCategory}  =  :newcontent 
    WHERE jobs_id = :jobs_id";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params); //This is what is binding the params

    //redirect 
    header("Location:admin.php");
    exit();
} else {
    //Invalid Column
    //Throw
}
```

You can also issue another query to read database schema aside from having a static whitelist.

**Suggestion:**
Use a DBAL like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). It will do most of this ground work for you.

Hopefully this is helpful!